# latex page with background grid lines problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I try to use background package to draw grid lines under text. It works but still one problem:

if the first line start with 'a', the position is located at the first grid line but the expected location should be the second grid line. If change it to 'b', then 'b' will occupy the first and second grid line,which is as expected.

Sounds like the grid lines offset not correct!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgPosition{current page text area.north west}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
       \def\offset{60pt}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\rows}{floor(\textheight/\offset)}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dx}{floor(40/3}
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\rows} {
        \foreach \j in {0,...,3} {
            \draw[line width=0.5pt] ([yshift=-\i*\offset-\j*\dx]O) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
        }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{vicent}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont 
\cursiveshape
\foreach \i in {a,...,f} {
\i \\
}
\foreach \i in {A,...,F} {
\i \\
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can cure this by appending `\vphantom{b}`. I tested that only without the vicent package, which happens not to b e part of my TeXLive installation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgPosition{current page text area.north west}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0;
       \def\offset{60pt}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\rows}{floor(\textheight/\offset)}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dx}{floor(40/3}
      \typeout{\the\textheight,\rows,\dx}
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\rows} {
        \foreach \j in {0,...,3} {
            \draw[line width=0.5pt] ([yshift=-\i*\offset-\j*\dx]O) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
        }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
%\usepackage{vicent}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont 
%\cursiveshape
\foreach \i in {a,...,f} {
\i\vphantom{b} \\
}
\foreach \i in {A,...,F} {
\i\vphantom{b} \\
}
\end{document}
```